# sudo make is returning errors

Tags: linux, robocup

I am installing the robocup simulator and followed these steps in this link [installing robocup steps](http://louissimons.com/2011/02/installing-robocup-soccer-simulator-on-ubuntu/) and this is what I find when I write the following command `sudo make` in monitor directory

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laudio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSM
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lICE
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXrender
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rcssmonitor] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssmonitor-15.1.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssmonitor-15.1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and this is the output when I write the same command `sudo make` in base directory

```
loader.cpp: In static member function ‘static boost::filesystem3::path  rcss::lib::Loader::stripDirName(const boost::filesystem3::path&)’:
loader.cpp:158:38: error: conversion from ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
make[4]: *** [loader.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssbase-12.1.3/rcssbase/lib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssbase-12.1.3/rcssbase/lib'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssbase-12.1.3/rcssbase'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssbase-12.1.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and this is what I get in server directory when calling the same command `sudo make`

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrcssclangparser
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [rcssserver] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssserver-15.2.2/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssserver-15.2.2/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mostafa/Desktop/robocup simulator/rcssserver-15.2.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

make is installed perfectly

Comment: do you have all of those libraries installed, including the devel versions of their packages?

Comment: yes rcssbase-12.1.3, rcssserver-15.1.0, rcssmonitor-15.2.2
do I need other files ?

Comment: audio, xt, png, etc... all of the `cannot find -lwhatever` stuff.

Comment: I don't have any idea about them ... would please help me with the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install libaudio-dev libpng-dev libxi-dev libglib2.0-dev libfontconfig-dev libxrender-dev
```

I know it's late :D
I hope you didn't given up robocup ;)

Answer (score 0):

1...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnurubuntu/rubuntu && sudo apt-get update
```

2...

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev build-essential rcsoccersim inkscape qt-sdk eclipse monodevelop openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

3...

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```